# Cannot install symfony with option --webapp

Tags: symfony

I try to install symfony v5.

Following the documentation, (https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/setup.html#creating-symfony-applications) i have the error "Incorrect usage: flag provided but not defined: --webapp".

Same error with symfony cli and composer.

How can i resolve this problem ? No help in the documentation... Each new version of symfony becomes more complicated. :-(

Thank you for your help.

Here's my configuration:
php: v7.3
symfony (CLI): v4.24.1
composer: v1.10.15

Comment: That is weird, but try the second code block where you have the `composr require webapp` line. This method should work.

Comment: if i try the second metthod, i have an error message "Could not find package webap"... really weird

Comment: Is it `webap` or `webapp` that it doesn't find. If the latter, maybe you don't have flex?

Comment: Sorry , it is **webapp**. Make a mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try to upgrade Your symfony version. For my symfony version (5.3.13) it works correctly

Comment: I update symfony version. And great, it solved ! With the new version, --webapp is found. Thanks you !

Comment: I agree, updating symfony corrects the issue.  Thanks.